# Code exiting try and going in catch after first executeQuery?

Tags: java, android, sql, exception

I am a beginner in android development. This is a part of my sign up code in my first android studio app: The code is going into catch right after the first execute query line and not executing my second query. If i check the Database a user is added but not a fan.

Any idea why? Any help is appreciated.

```
    try {
         Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
         if (con == null) {
             z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
         } else {
             Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             String query1 = "INSERT INTO Usertb Values ('" + userid + "', '" + Password + "', '" + 1 + "')";
             stmt.executeQuery(query1);
             String query = "INSERT INTO Fan Values ('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "','" + Age + "', '" + Email + "', '"
                            + null + "', '" + i + "', '" + null + "')";
             rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
             if (rs.next()) {
                 z = "Sign Up successfull";
                 isSuccess = true;
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         isSuccess = false;
         z = "Exceptions";
     }
```

Comment: Is it hard to say without looking at the exception/error trace. Please include it in your question.

Comment: @user2004685 i have no error displayed it just catches an exception and does not say why.

Comment: Start logging the exception or at least print it to the console to see what is going on inside your `catch` block.

Comment: @user200468 i added this: catch (SQLException se) {
                    z="sql exception";} and it went straight to this catch now.

Comment: Well if you want to print it to the console then you'll have to do something like `System.out.println(ex);`

Comment: @user2004685 it shows sql exception as toast now

Comment: Well as I said before, it is hard to say what's going wrong without looking at the real exception. But it seems that there is something wrong with your query. Double check if you are passing the correct column names and data-types. Maybe the last parameter in your `query1` is `Integer` and not `String`?

Comment: @user2004685 this does not seem to be the problem because if i swap the queries it executes add fan correctly then stops and does not add a user. It looks like it can only execute one query at a time.

Comment: *"It looks like it can only execute one query at a time. "* No, it is not like that. There is some problem with your code. Maybe because you are doing `stmt.executeQuery(query);` twice and you have Primary Key constraints which is preventing the duplicate entry and hence throwing the error.

Comment: @user2004685 they are two different queries on two different tables and i removed all the links between them. So there should be no duplicates problem.

Comment: I don't see any difference here: `stmt.executeQuery(query);
             rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);` Just that you are executing `query` two times and then second time you are taking the result in a ResultSet.

Comment: @user2004685 ohh okay sorry i missed that line i thought that you were talking about execute query and query1. Will check.

Answer (score 1):

One has to use executeUpdate (INSERT/UPDATE) instead of executeQuery.

```
    String sql =  "INSERT INTO Usertb(userid, passw, n) VALUES (?, PASSWORD(?), ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        stmt.setString(1, userName);
        stmt.setString(2, password);
        stmt.setInt(3, 1);
        int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(query1); // 1  when 1 record inserted

        if (updateCount != 0) {
            // If you want to use an autincrement primary key:
            try (ResultSet rsKeys = stm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (rsKeys.next()) {
                    long id = rsKeys.getLong(1);
                }
            }
        }
    } // Closes stmt
```

Furthermore it is very important to use prepared statements to prevent **SQL injection**. It also takes care of single quotes and backslash in the strings.

Additionally there is shown how to use AUTOINCR fields, to retrieve a database generated key, for example for the second INSERT.

For the second use a new PreparedStatement.

Passwords should better be stored encrypted in the database, should someone steal the data. You might look into that subject. My solution is quite minimal, look for seeding and other encryption functions.

Comment: I tried replacing executeQuery with executeUpdate, and used prepared statements. Now it's no longer adding to user and still showing sqlException.

Comment: Comment out the second statement. When that works (as in fact you already told), then the problem is with the second statement. That  null, will probably not work as such. A stacktrace in general names the exact error.

Comment: I tried only executing the first query using update and prepared stmt and commented the second. It did not add the user to db and showed an sqlException aswell.